# como enviar datos entre dos elementos hijo con angular 4

Tags: angular

Tengo dos tres elementos

- Padre
- Hijo 1
- Hijo 2

lo que necesito es poder enviar un arreglo de datos del elemento Hijo 1 al Hijo 2

```html
<!-- Elemento Hijo 1 -->
<app-rango-form></app-rango-form>
<!-- Elemento Hijo 2 -->
<app-tablero-deudas-table></app-tablero-deudas-table>
```

Comment: Crea un shared service. Es la manera más sencilla.

Answer (score 0):

Si solo necesitas enviar datos de un componente a otro, lo mejor seria crear un servicio e inyectarlo en ambos componentes.

Simplemente creas un archivo servicio.service.ts, que contenga el decorador de @Injectable

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class MiServicio {
// variable en la que puedes guardar informacion para acceder con el otro componente
    variableServicio: {};
}
```

Lo declaras como provider en tu modulo:

```
components: [MiComponente, ChildAComponent, ChildBComponent],
providers: [MiServicio] // aqui declaras todos los servicios que vayas a usar
```

En tu componente importas el servicio y lo inyectas en tu constructor:

```
import {MiSericio} from './servicio.service';

constructor(public servicio: MiServicio){}
// y accedes a la variable dentro del servicio de la siguiente forma
// tambien puedes usar observables y funciones en el servicio y llamarlos usando this.servicio
miVar = this.servicio.variableServicio;
```

Aqui dejo articulos acerca del uso de servicios
https://stories.devacademy.la/tour-of-heroes-angular-2-uso-de-servicios-parte-3-6ed0671867e5
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 0):

Creo que la forma más adecuada (y a efectos técnicos puede ser la más sencilla) es utilizar `@Input` y `@Output` para la comunicación entre componentes.

La idea de usar un servicio está bien, pero esto conlleva a pensar en el binding entre los componentes cuando estos datos cambien (lo que es habitual)
entonces empezamos a notar, que en el servicio debemos incluir el uso de `Observables` y `BehaviorSubjects` para el correcto funcionamiento del binding.

Por eso pienso que: sin descartar la idea del service, en la mayoría de estos casos lo mejor es utilizar `@Input` y `@Output` que considero es más acorde, ya que se trata sencillamente de compartir dinámicamente (aclaro que no es lo que precisamente solicitaste en tu pregunta, pero casi de seguro es algo que necesitarás más tarde) un dato entre componentes. La idea es algo así:

AppComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        <!-- Elemento Hijo 1 -->
        <app-rango-form (datosModificadosEvent)="setDatos($event)"></app-rango-form>
        <!-- Elemento Hijo 2 -->
        <app-tablero-deudas-table [datos]="datosCompartidos"></app-tablero-deudas-table>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {

    datosCompartidos: any[];

    constructor() { }

    setDatos($event) {
        this.datosCompartidos = $event;
    }

}
```

Componente hijo 1

```
import { Component, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-rango-form',
    template: ``
})
export class RangoFormComponent {

    datos: any[];

    @Output() datosModificadosEvent = new EventEmitter<any[]>();

    constructor() { }

    // Ejemplo...
    cambiarDatos() {
        this.datos.push("Algo");

        // Notificar
        this.notificarCambios();
    }

    // Si cambian los datos de algún modo
    notificarCambios() {
        this.datosModificadosEvent.emit(this.datos);
    }
}
```

Componente hijo 2

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tablero-deudas-table',
    template: ``
})
export class TableroDeudasTableComponent {

    @Input() datos: any[];

    constructor() { }
}
```

Lo planteo como otra posibilidad, pero reconozco que creo que es la mejor para este caso.

Docs de Angular sobre el tema: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.